# How does Glide load image asynchronously?

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a `RecyclerView` and each item of `RecyclerView` is having `ImageView`. I am loading the image in that `ImageView` using `Glide`. I saw some blog says `Glide` can load image asynchronously but I can not see this from the code below. It seems it only load one image when `onBindViewHolder` is invoked. How does it show asynchrony?

```
   public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<GalleryItem> mList;

        public GalleryAdapter(Context mContext, List<GalleryItem> mList) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mList = mList;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView mImageView;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_gallery,
                parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            GalleryItem item = mList.get(position);
            holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(item.getUrl())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mList.size();
        }

        public void addAll(List<GalleryItem> newList) {
            mList.addAll(newList);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mList.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you scroll the recyclerView, `onBindViewHolder()` is called many times to load each item, and for each item the Glide downloads the image in a thread and sets it to the imageView and even the image caching is done by it.

Comment: @dashenswen The quote you read is not referring to the code you provided. It is about how Glide does the asynchronous work behind the hood. Basically Glides create a specific numbers of thread and the loading and caching is being organized in a form of Queues.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB'. Yeah, I read the document again and am impressed by it. By the way, do you know why they can cache so many photos? The document says Glide cache image in memory. But when I scroll my recycleview and download 5000+ images, it does not has OOM problem. Do you know why? Even Glide download image with lower quality, it is really impresses me in this point.

Comment: @Enzokie. Thank you for your clarification. Do you know why it can load so many images without OOM problem? Glide download images with lower quality but I can keep at least 5000 images in my memory(it should be more than this).

Comment: @dashenswen its because it uses the the Data structure called **LRU (least recently used)**. Whenever it is full it will destroy those old image to claim some memories then load the newest downloaded image. Also Glide reduces the size of image by removing some color so that it can save space (Its hard to notice though by just looking ;) ).

Comment: @Enzokie. Great idea about using LRU. I saw some guys write LRU for image downloading. But when I scroll back to the top, the url does not re-load since I write the url generator and monitor the output in the console. Does Glide keep all the url in memory?  LRU is used for image caching, which is reasonable. How does it download image when I scroll back to the previous page(even back to top)?

Comment: `Does Glide keeps all the url in memory?` Yes but you can modify it to use the phone storage although memory is much faster. `How does it download?` Actually it does not download again because it is in the cache already (That's the main purpose of a cache) unless it was wiped out because it is too old and the lib needs to store a fresh image in which the allocated memory is not enough. If you have followup question just email me because I am not allowed to answer it here :)

Answer (score 2):

According to glide documentation [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/GenericRequestBuilder.html#into(int,%20int)) and [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads) you should use the into() method that returns FutureTarget and not the one that returns a Target. This method take width and height, not an ImageView : "If you actually want to interact with a decoded image on a background thread, instead of using downloadOnly you can use the version of into() that returns a FutureTarget."

Comment: I am not quite understand your explanation. Is it related to explain how Glide load image asynchronously?

Comment: not very good explanation, I really wounder how this answer gets 3 up votes, it's not related to the question, it's correct and everything but not for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The load method does it's work asynchronously when you load images to ImageView take a look on these threads:

1. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1209
2. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads

In the third thread it's mentioning how to make "SYNCHRONOUS" load for an image to be used in a background thread meaning that it's by default made asynchronously

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Glide.with(applicationContext)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .asBitmap()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(500, 500)
    .get()
```

and it's saying also this call above CAN"T be done on main thread but they did not mention any of that when they were talking about the normal loading into an imageView which is also an evidence that the normal load is made async then automatically after loading it moves the result to main thread to be used by method into(imageView).

I really tried to find it explicit but could not find it anywhere in docs so I thought it's obvious because they did not tell us to manage the background threading like in the mentioned case above.